# iOS8 and iAd: Adding an AdBannerView in Storyboard - What size does it need to be?

Tags: ios, storyboard, iad

If I add an iAd in Storyboard, what size does this frame need to be? I want my app to be universal for all iPhones and iPads, so how do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

For an iPhone, the BannerView should be 50 points by 320 points in Portrait view and 32 points by 480 points in Landscape.

For an iPad, the BannerView should be 66 points by 768 points in Portrait view and 66 points by 1024 points in Landscape.

From what I can see the iOS iAd Programming Guide does not cover the concept of using size classes, so you may want to use 2 different Storyboards for your app.  I have provided a link to Apple's documentation below.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH1-SW1